# How to find observation with the max value?

Tags: r

I have the data frame af.df.
`Country` values are the names of the `countries`, and the numbers are how many times they show up in the data.

```
> table(af.df$country)

          Algeria                 Benin              Botswana 
              109                   148                   139 
     Burkina Faso               Burundi              Cameroon 
              115                   122                    13 
       Cape Verde                 Egypt                 Gabon 
              149                   135                   107 
            Ghana                Guinea           Ivory Coast 
              259                   131                    63 
            Kenya               Lesotho               Liberia 
              260                   139                   115 
       Madagascar                Malawi                  Mali 
              120                   270                   129 
        Mauritius               Morocco            Mozambique 
              140                   121                   293 
          Namibia                 Niger               Nigeria 
              120                   125                   243 
São Tomé and Príncipe           Senegal          Sierra Leone 
              143                   129                   135 
     South Africa                 Sudan             Swaziland 
              269                   119                   134 
         Tanzania                  Togo               Tunisia 
              141                   137                   153 
           Uganda                Zambia              Zimbabwe 
              260                   123                   247
```

What would I do to pull the `max` value?
(Which is Mozambique, 293?)

If I use max, it pulls out:

```
> max(af.df$country)
[1] "Zimbabwe"
```

Can someone explain why that is?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider an example of `cyl` in `mtcars` dataset.

```
table(mtcars$cyl)

 4  6  8 
11  7 14
```

Now if you want to know the maximum count available in above `table()` output then simply use `max`

```
max(table(mtcars$cyl))

[1] 14
```

If you want to know the maximum count as well as the value to which this count belongs to then you can try `sort`

```
sort(table(mtcars$cyl), decreasing = T)[1]

 8 
14
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Really nice solution

Answer (score 0):

In your case max(af.df$country) returns you the maximum of a character list value ( = to the last alphabetic order ). If you want the maximum value of a table(). I suggest you to use this tricks :

```
table_country <- table(af.df$country)
names(table_country)[table_country == max(table_country)]
```

Hope that will work and answer your question.

Gottavianoni

Answer (score 0):

`table(af.df$country)[which.max(af.df$country)]` should have the desired result.

Here's an example, sampling 100 random lowercase letters.  You can see that `u` is the most common letter:

```
> set.seed(1)
> dat = sample(letters, 100, TRUE)
> table(dat)
dat
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
2 3 3 3 2 4 6 1 6 5 6 4 7 2 2 2 5 4 5 3 8 4 5 4 3 1 
> table(dat)[which.max(table(dat))]
u 
8
```

`which.max(table(dat))` by itself returns the position of the most common entry:

```
> which.max(table(dat))
 u 
21
```

One caveat is that `which.max` returns the *first* maximum of a vector.  This may be what you want. If instead you want *all* maxima, then explicitly find the maximum and look for entries in the table equal to it.  Here's a sample from the alphabet with two most common letters:

```
> set.seed(2)
> dat = sample(letters, 100, TRUE)
> tab = table(dat)
> tab
dat
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
4 3 3 5 7 4 2 5 3 5 6 5 3 2 5 1 2 4 2 3 3 6 5 1 4 7 
> tab[tab == max(tab)]
dat
e z 
7 7
```